# Awk syntax error with time layout from logs

Tags: awk, syntax

I'm getting an syntax error with awk when I'm doing this one liner :

```
awk '{ if ($3 == '16' && $4 == '23:59:44') {print $0} }' /var/log/radius/radius.log
```

it gives me a syntax error from the time field. However, when I'm doing:

```
awk '{ print $4 }' /var/log/radius/radius.log
```

this gives me the proper format for the time hh:mm:ss so I don't understand why it doesn't work from my one liner ?

Cheers!

Comment: What's in `/var/log/radius/radius.log` ?

Comment: use double-quotes for you value comparisons: ```"16"``` - same for the other

Comment: Think about what each quote **means**: `awk '<in awk>'<back in shell>'<back in awk>' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes `'`  should be used to start and end the `awk`'s main program, you should use `"` instead here for comparison.

***OP's code fix:***

```
awk '{ if ($3 == 16 && $4 == "23:59:44") {print $0} }' Input_file
```

***OR above could be shorten to(`awk` sh way to do):***

```
awk '($3 == 16 && $4 == "23:59:44")' Input_file
```